# MS Excel: Group by sum

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find a way of using functions to figure out when an account will be tech refreshed.  I can refresh 25 accounts per week.

I have a list of account numbers with a total number of computers for each account number.  I am trying to find a formula where I can group account numbers so that I can have a total of 25 computers per group (or close to it to have entire accounts in one group).  With this "ranking" I am going to assign dates to it.

I'm trying to auto-fill the rank and Tech Refresh columns:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Use solver. It can easily solve such a task.

Comment: @Akina

What solver are you talking about?

Comment: The Solver Add-in is a Microsoft Office Excel add-in program that is available when you install Microsoft Office or Excel.

Comment: @Akina

This looks like it may work.  Any suggestions on how to use it?  I'm hitting up the YouTube right now.

Comment: What about accounts with greater than 25 computers? Once you determine how you want to handle that, solver might help. However, it will only provide one solution, if at all. It may also be painfully slow. These optimization problems are deceptively simple. Their difficulty has given rise to the whole field of Operations Research.

Comment: @ctrl_alt_dstry,, my observation,, considering sample data Group on Account Nu. will useless since are unique value,, for sort & group duplicates are the key feature,, currently Dates are ideal to sort & group,, and if you want to  get or as called refreshed,, 25 accounts per week then you may think for filter max 25 rows for the week, which can be calculated on the basis of dates available!!

Comment: @ctrl_alt_dstry,, better share the expected output will clear all confusions!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st cell is A1, just put this in C2, then drag downwards.

```
=INT((ROW()-1)/25)+1
```

Idea : use row number as group integer generator.

kindly share if it solves/not. ( :